# Microsoft Teams App - Custom Connector | Markdown or HTML does not work on Connector Configuration page

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

We recently created a Microsoft Teams app **JustCall** with a custom connector. The app is now successfully listed in the Microsoft Teams app store. But, we are facing markdown formatting issue with the Connector description on Connector configuration page. The long app description that we have defined in the Teams app `manifest.json` file contains markdown which works fine on the app description page. The same description also shows up on connector configuration page, but, in this case, markdown is not rendering and the text displays inside Teams app as it is along with the markdown symbols. The Microsoft Teams app review team confirmed that the issue is at the Teams platform side. Sharing here screenshots from [app description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUa84.png) (markdown is working) and [connector configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVtip.png) pages (markdown is not working) for reference.

We have also checked some other connectors from Teams App portal and found that the app description and the connector description are different. And probably, the connection description is coming directly from the description defined for the connector in the [Connector portal](https://outlook.office.com/connectors/publish) instead from the app `manifest.json` .

Currently, the connector description on connector configuration page is broken in Microsoft Teams due to formatting issue. We are really hoping to figure out any way to make the markdown work on the connector configuration page or, display the connector description from connector portal instead of app description, if possible.

Comment: Same issue is being tracked here at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1375884/markdown-formatting-issue-in-microsoft-teams-conne. Please check Microsoft QnA forum for further updates.